# Reload Last Carousel Image On Click

Tags: javascript, jquery, carousel, page-refresh

Can someone help me create a single script (vanilla or jquery) so that whenever I click on an image, the next time I refresh my browser the carousel loads that clicked image?

This is what I have so far:

When I click on an image in my carousel, this jquery script alerts me the index number of that slide:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#myCarousel').on('click', '.mySlides', function () {
        alert( $(this).index('.mySlides')+1 );
    });
});
//Alert! 7 (ie. Current image slide is 7/10, etc)
```

I have a separte vanilla javascript when I refresh my browser, the carousel loads a specific image but I have to manually insert the index number:

```
window.addEventListener("load", (event) => {
  currentSlide(7); 
});
```

I've reached my limit on how to make this work as a single script. Appreciate all the help :)

Answer (score 0):

You will need to save the index somewhere, e.g localstorage.

to save the index

```
localStorage.setItem("index", 7);
```

to get the index

```
const currentIndex = localStorage.getItem("index");
```

For example

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#myCarousel').on('click', '.mySlides', function () {
        alert( $(this).index('.mySlides')+1 );
        localStorage.setItem("index", $(this).index('.mySlides')+1);
    });

});

window.addEventListener("load", (event) => {
      const currentIndex = localStorage.getItem("index");
  currentSlide(currentIndex); 
});
```

[localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage)

Comment: This works, thank you for the help! By chance, could you provide a script that stores the last viewed image slide without clicking on the image? Regardless, thanks for the feedback!

Comment: I dunno how your carousel works, but u can put the localstorage.setItem on where it calls for next image